# JS multiple function with the same name

Tags: javascript, function

I use different javascript function. The problem is that they have the same name so they overwrite each other. I would like to put a different name but so far it didn't work.

Here one of the function and how I use it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').multiDatesPicker({
            altField: '#date',
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        });
</script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

The other function start like this too `$(function() {}` and use the same way `<div id="date"></div>`

I try to put `$(function name()` but it didn't work.
Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: That function is anonymous, so it can't be overwritten.

Comment: Do you mean you have a library conflicting with the `$` syntax? If so, use noConflict() : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: yes it's this problem but i can't find the way to solve it

Answer (score 3):

This is a call to `$` (in your case, it's jQuery), with a single argument, which happens to be an *anonymous* function. It doesn't have a name, and having more than one occurrence of this pattern will not "overwrite" the previous:

```
$(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Passing a function to `$` is just shorthand for `$(document).ready()`. If you need more than one, you should be able to simply combine them:

```
$(function() {
    // Initialise your date picker
    // Do some other stuff
});
```

Comment: if I combine them only the first one work and not the second one  like: $(function() {   $('#datepicker').multiDatesPicker({...});
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({..});
});

Comment: Then something is wrong with the second one. Does it work if you remove the first one?

Comment: yes it works. If I put the second one on top it's the first one (become second) which stop to work

Comment: I try to use it, but I need jquery code also so it seems doesn't work correctly, here the link in case http://jsfiddle.net/GNjtA/1/

Answer (score 0):

that function is shorthand for $(document).ready() which is just a binding to the ready event of the document.  all that means is you can have as many of them as you want without overwriting eachother.

see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BywYQ/)

```
    $(function()
  {
      alert('func1');
  });
$(function()
  {
      alert('func2');
  });
```